# How to stop shell script if curl failed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have script that used curl 
when i pass wrong parameters to script curl failed but script continue executing.
I have tried use `curl -f/--fail` parameter but problem does not solved.
What is the best way to stop script?

I have founded my mistake.
I used `curl` command into another command

```
echo `curl --fail ... || exit 1`
```

After removing echo command curl become working properly.
Thank you for answer, it is also useful.

Comment: check for curl's exit code, also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822621/how-to-exit-if-a-command-failed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check for exit code using `$?`:

```
exit_status = $?
if [ $exit_status != 0 ]
  then
    exit $exit_status
fi
```

If you want to analyze exit status, take a look at the `Exit codes` section from  `man curl` page. There are a lot of different codes, depending on why it failed.

**EDIT :** You can use `command1 || command2` as well. `command2` is executed if and only if `command1` has failed:

```
curl .... || exit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `exit` if `curl` ends with a non-zero exit code:

```
curl http://www.example.com || exit 1
```

Or, make your script exit on error:

```
set -e
curl http://www.example.com
```