# Check to see if server is up

Tags: linux, bash, logging, curl

1. Create dir `logs` (for outputted logs)
2. Create a script `IsTheServerUp.bash`
3. Write a script to check if the server is up
4. Log(`echo`) the outcome to the file
5. Use `curl` command to check the server
6. Use rules above to write your bash

   - Use `curl` to request a webpage from a server
   - Provide the `--output/dev/null` option + argument to suppress output.
   - Check return status (`$?`)

     - If status `0`(success)
     - If not (`0`) error message
   - Include status code and the date/time stamp.
   - Log outputted message to `mylog.log`

My current code which doesn't work:

```
#! bin/bash
if curl -s --head  --request GET http://opx.com/opx/version | grep "200 OK"    > /dev/null && curl -s --head --request GET http://oss.com/version | grep "200   OK" > /dev/null;
exit 0
```

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: when I type curl "http://.." It just outputs a list Of HTML and CSS for that website

Comment: That's what `curl` is supposed to do. I suggest you review the manual (`man curl`) to understand the tool you are trying to use.

Comment: Perhaps [How to check whether a command such as curl completed without error?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124918/how-to-check-whether-a-command-such-as-curl-completed-without-error) or [How to stop shell script if curl failed](https://superuser.com/questions/742408/how-to-stop-shell-script-if-curl-failed) will be of help to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. I'll try to re edit this question because I made some changes.

Comment: This looks like a school assignment...reading man pages for the tools you use is the way to go.